# LibreOffice tooltip for disabled control

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

In LibreOffice Calc I have a form with checkbox controls. I use the Help Text property to display tooltips for them, but this only works when the control is enabled. How can I make a tooltip display also for a disabled control?

Libreoffice version 5.3.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that this is not possible to do, at least not the way I originally intended.

My solution: Remove the label text from the checkbox control, instead add it in a separate label control. Then put the tooltip (help text) on the label instead. It will not be as obvious as before when the checkbox is disabled as the label text is not greyed out, but the tooltip will always display.